# FindFirstFile/FindNextFile with long running operations

Tags: winapi, directory, filesystems

Is it ok to enumerate a large directory where a long running operation is performed on each file using the FindFirstFile/FindNextFile api?

It may take my application 10-30 minutes to process all files returned by a directory search in a directory with 10,000+ files at the same time there is file creation/deletion activity in the directory.

I'm concerned that Windows might not be happy with this usage pattern under the covers but I have not been able to find any recommendations one way or the other.

Comment: yes, this is ok. `Windows might not be happy` - why you decide this ? no any problem here. only issue for you - until you will be enumerate so long - new files can be add to folder, which you not enumerate, or some deleted

Comment: @RbMm I reasoned that since Windows needs to keep a handle open to an old snapshot of the directory there is the potential for a poor implementation by the kernel so I decided to inquire.

Comment: yes, handle for folder will be open. but no any `snapshot` is held.

Comment: for be more clear - when you call `ZwQueryDirectoryFile` - FS not create any "snapshot" of current directory state. instead in FileObject associated with directory file exist "offset" to current *DIRENT* - this is similar file offset. when you enumerate file - this "offset" is incremented (if `restartscan==false`) - so no any additional memory hold. only file handle (but every process always have how minimum serveral files opened)

Comment: Windows is already multi-tasking, so whether it takes 1 second or 1 minute or 1 hour, there is no conceptual difference.

Comment: if interesting internal implementation - [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/filesys/fastfat/dirctrl.c#L226) for FAT. but NTFS have similar. look for `Ccb->OffsetToStartSearchFrom` and `CurrentVbo`

Comment: If files are deleted during the operation it's not a problem, if you find a file that doesn't exist any longer just ignore it, but what do you want to happen happen if new files are created during the processing ?

Comment: if new files will be added during enumeration may be *UB*. it can be or can not be enumerated.

Comment: @RbMm thank you so much for the explanation.  this completely clarifies the issue for me and i can code accordingly.  actually, 1 other question... is there any chance the directory entries get reordered in the midst of an enumeration?

Comment: @Michael, that's not always true - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42404802/886887).  It is unusual, but there are cases where files being deleted during enumeration will cause other files to be overlooked.